# Why am I getting this absurd result by integrating Taylor series?

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion

Just like the integration of the Taylor series of $\,\sin x\,$ gives $\,\cos x +C. \,$ I did the same with the general taylor series.
The integration of the taylor series of $f(x)$ around x=a is:
$$f(a)x+\frac{(x-a)^2}{2}f^{'}(a)+......$$
which gives $a*f(a)$ at x=a.

I integrated the general Taylor series around $x=a$ of any function and evaluated it at $x=a.$ That gives $a\cdot f(a),$

which is absolutely false because it would mean that the value of the integral of any function $f(x)$ at $x=a$ is $a\cdot f(a)$.

And, it means that the definite integral of any function from $a$ to $b$ is $bf(b)-af(a)$ which is false.

So, what did I do wrong?

Comment: What exactly did you do?  You have to be careful about manipulating infinite series because you can only rearrange them if they're absolutely convergent.

Comment: @lordoftheshadows I didn't understand that. Did you mean that I can use the integral of a taylor series at $x=a$ only to evaluate the integral at x not equal to a?

Comment: Please show you integration of "the general Taylor series" and then evaluating at $x=a$.  What you state is not very clear at all.

Comment: @amWhy I've added it.

Comment: Thanks for your responsiveness, @Dove!

Comment: Note that the integration of the series also requires a constant $C$. The primitive of a function does NOT define an unique function.

Comment: @MiguelAtencia What about the definite integral? That would cancel the constant. Doesn't what I've done here mean that the definite integral of any function from a to b is bf(b)-af(a)?

Comment: @Dove Nope, because the parentheses in the next terms do not cancel at $x=b$. The point is that, without additional data, you will never be able to calculate the value of the integral: it is (more or less hidden) part of the statement of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the integration constant, which makes

$$F(a)=f(a)a+C$$ which is perfectly valid as it can take any value.

And when performing the definite integration, you assumed that $F(b)=f(b)b$, which is wrong.

The true relation is

$$F(b)-F(a)=\left.f(a)x+f'(a)\frac{(x-a)^2}2+f''(a)\frac{(x-a)^3}3+\cdots\right|_a^b\\
=f(a)(b-a)+f''(a)\frac{(b-a)^2}2+f''(a)\frac{(b-a)^3}3+\cdots$$

Comment: No. I took the taylor series around x=b to get F(b)=f(b)b+C and subtracted f(a)a+C from it.

Comment: @Dove: don't be bad faith, there is no mention of $C$ in your post. And you may not mix a development around $a$ with one around $b$.